Fallacy in the proof of existence of a one-to-one correspondence from $^{\{0\}}\mathbb{N}$ to $^{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N}$
Denote by $^{S}F$ the set of all functions from set $S$ to set $F$. For example, let $S=\{0, 1\}$ and $F=\mathbb{N}$, then $^{S}F$ denotes the set of all functions from $\{0, 1\}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. This set of all functions can be represented by the set of ordered pairs $(x_0, x_1)$.
Using the notation, I've come up with a proof of existence of a one-to-one correspondence (or a bijection) from $^{\{0\}}\mathbb{N}$ to $^{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N}$  as follows:
By using the diagonal argument, we can easily obtain that there's a bijection from $^{\{0\}}\mathbb{N}$ to $^{\{0, 1\}}\mathbb{N}$. Also, by using the same argument we can deduce that there's a bijection from from $^{\{0\}}\mathbb{N}$ to $^{\{0,
 1, \dots, k\}}\mathbb{N}, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Because, this is true for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then we can deduce that there's a bijection from $^{\{0\}}\mathbb{N}$ to $^{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N}$. To see this, suppose to the contrary that this is not true. Then, there must exist some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there's no bijection from $^{\{0\}}\mathbb{N}$ to $^{\{0, 1,\dots, k\}}\mathbb{N}$. However, this contradicts what we just obtained from the previous paragraph. So, we conclude that there's bijection from $^{\{0\}}\mathbb{N}$ to $^{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N}$.
However, the conclusion is not true because this leads to the real number is countable. Still, I can see for myself what's wrong with the above proof?

Proving that something is true for each natural number does not prove that is valid for the whole set of natural numbers. Consider the easier example: For each $k\in \Bbb N$ the set ${0,1,\ldots,k}$ is finite. Then the whole set $\Bbb N$ is finite?

Fourth paragraph is inadequate.  That "${1,2,\cdots,k}$ is finite" is true for all $k \in \Bbb{N}$, but does not lead to "$\Bbb{N}$ is finite."

By "one-to-one map" do you mean injection or bijection?

Perhaps the mistake is in the unsupported assertion "there must exist some $k\in\mathbb N$ . . ."

@jjagmath, I see where I've mistaken now, thank you!

@bof, there was a typo, "one-to-one" should have been used instead of "bijection". I've updated the question.

But the existence of a one-to-one (i.e. injective) map from $^{{0}}\mathbb N$ to $^\mathbb N\mathbb N$ is trivial.

@user14111, could you please elaborate on it? It's not trivial for me. In fact, I don't think it could exist.

The map $(x)\mapsto(x,x,x,\dots)$ is an injection from $^{{0}}\mathbb N$ to $^\mathbb N\mathbb N$. Of course there is no bijection or surjection from  $^{{0}}\mathbb N$ to $^\mathbb N\mathbb N$.

Kt Student: There is a terminological confusion here. "One-to-one map" is a synonym for "injective map", and of course there is an injective map from $^{{0}}\mathbb{N}$ to $^\mathbb{N}\mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, "one-to-one correspondence" is sometimes used as a synonym for "bijective map", and there is no bijective map from $^{{0}}\mathbb{N}$ to $^\mathbb{N}\mathbb{N}$. Because of the possibility of confusing these terms, as you did, it is much preferable to write "bijective map" instead of "one-to-one correspondence". @user14111

@AlexKruckman, the two very similar terminologies did confuse me. I intend to mean the bijection (or one-to-one correspondence) not injective function or (one-to-one mapping). And as many have pointed out, there does not exist a bijection from $^{{0}}\mathbb{N}$ to $^{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N}$.
